# Get data on the basis of conditions in entity framework 3.5 with include

Tags: entity-framework

I am using entity framework 3.5 for my application.

I want load data based on some condition e.g.

```
var data = from e in context.Employee.Include("Employee.Projects") where e.IsActive select e;
```

Using this, I will get all the Employees which are active with their project details. But I want to load only those projects which are active. So, how to load only active projects using the query?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conditional Include version. Take a look at these links at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085462/conditional-include-in-linq-to-entities) and [MSMVPS](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entityframework-include-with-func.aspx), hope they will help.