# Include path expression tree error

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

```
Expression<Func<SystemUser, object>>[] includeProperties = {
    x => x.Company.CompanyAddresses.Where(z=>z.AddressTypeId==5)
                                   .Select(y => y.Address.Country.CountryRegions)
};
var user = _SystemUserRepository.GetById(userID, includeProperties);
```

while I am executing the above query, it throws exception as "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties."

if I remove "where" clause from query, it executes fine.

could any one explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first Include the property.

Try something like this:

```
x => x.Company.Include(y=>y.CompanyAddresses)
              .Where(z=>z.CompanyAddresses.AddressTypeId==5)
              .Select(y => y.Address.Country.CountryRegions)
```

You can also refer to [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1951762.aspx?Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20defined%20Where%20inside%20Include) and also check this [SO Post (conditional include in linq to entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085462/conditional-include-in-linq-to-entities)