# Entity Framework eager loading based on a specific attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The current setup of EF in my application is lazy loading, which is great for the most part. However, I am lost trying work out how to load a list of related entities based on their `IsEnabled` bit attribute.

In this example I am just returning a list of entities.

```
return Context.Entities.ToList()
```

Let's say the `Entities` object contains a list of `ChildEntities` like so:

```
public class Entities
{        
    private string EntityName;

    private List<ChildEntities> ChildEntities;
}

public class ChildEntites
{        
    private string ChildEntityName;
    private bool IsEnabled;
}
```

I want to only want to get out the `ChildEntities` based on their `IsEnabled` flag when loading the list of `Entities`.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible using `Include()` for eager loading, but maybe the lazy loaded `Context.Entities.Where(e => e.IsEnabled).ToList()` is fast enough? This where should run on the DB before any objects are materialized.

Comment: It is not possible to use eager loading (Include) because it doesn't support filtering, Include always loads the whole collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using a projection**

```
var entities = context.Entities
                      .Select(x => new {x, x.ChildEntities.Where(y => y.IsEnabled))
                      .ToList() // resolve from database before selecting the main entity
                      .Select(x => x.x);
```

**Using a third party library**

EF+ Query IncludeFilter allow you to easily filter related entities

```
var entities = context.Entities.IncludeFilter(x => x.ChildEntities.Where(y => y.IsEnabled))
                               .ToList();
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [EF+](http://entityframework-plus.net/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Include()` method to load all child entities and then select only those which are enabled like

```
Context.Entities.Include("ChildEntites").Select(c => e.IsEnabled == true)
```

Another way would be to get the filter entities and then run the query as shown [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085462/conditional-include-in-linq-to-entities)

```
var data = from e in Context.Entities
            select new
            {
                Entities = e,
                Childs = e.ChildEntites.Where(c => c.IsEnabled == true) 
            };

var Results = data.ToArray().Select(x => x.Entities);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to filter when you load related entities in case that you use lazy loading or eager loading unless you project your query to an anonymous type or a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), but if you have an entity instance,you can load related entities based on a condition using explicit loading:

```
var entity=context.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
context.Entry(entity) 
        .Collection(b => b.ChildEntities) 
        .Query() 
        .Where(ce => ce.IsEnabled == true) 
        .Load();
```

If that doesn't satisfy what you are trying to achieve because you need to load the entire entity collection, then, as I said before, you should project your query to a custom class or an anonymous type:

```
 var query= from e in Context.Entities.Include(c=>c.ChildEntities)
            select new EntityDTO
            {
                EntityName= e.EntityName,
                ChildEntites= e.ChildEntites.Where(c => c.IsEnabled == true) 
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways I would recommend this approach. I would either lazy load where IsEnabled = false and eager load in a separate call where IsEnabled = true OR once you have the lazy loaded collection, in a separate call, get the children where IsEnabled = true. I don't believe you will be able to do this in one call. The other option would be a stored procedure. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it in the following manner.

Create a new method in your model Entities. Lets call it ChildEntitiesEnabled

```
 public ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildEntitiesEnabled()
 {
      //First I get the full list using the lazy loading...
      var allChildEntities=ChildEntities.ToList();

      //do further processing if there is data
      if(allChildEntities!=null && allChildEntities.Count()>0)
      {

         var childEntitiesEnabled =  ChildEntities.Where(x=>x.Enabled==true).ToList();

         return childEntitiesEnabled;
      }

      return null; //or you can return an empty list...
 }
```

I like this method because you can use it anywhere the model is available without complicated code strewn all over the place. Also, you dont lose all the ChildEntities data... that is available too from the original call.